# Getting Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot' error when trying to install Django on GoDaddy w/ cPanel

Tags: python, django, apache, cpanel, shared-hosting

I currently have a website running on Godaddy with the "Economy Linux Hosting with cPanel" plan and I want to use Django on the website. I followed the instructions given [in this tutorial](https://libyanspider.com/knowledge/install-run-python-django-using-cpanel/) 
and also [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffqMZ5IcmSY) but when I try to test it by going to the "[website].com/admin" page, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. When I look at the Error page on cPanel, I see this error every time I try to access that page.

NOTE: Omitted cPanel username and database info.

```
/home/[cPanel username]/public_html/test/.htaccess: Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

This is what my .htaccess looks like (it's auto-created when I perform the "Setup Python App" process in cPanel).

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/[cPanel Username]/myapp"
PassengerBaseURI "/."
PassengerPython "/home/[cPanel Username]/virtualenv/myapp/3.6/bin/python3.6"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
```

"/home/[cPanel Username]/myapp" is the Django project root folder with manage.py and also passenger_wsgi.py, [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UMt.png).
[image]

[Here's how I setup Django in the "Setup Python App" page in cPanel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fg2Z.jpg)
[image]

This is the passenger_wsgi.py it created:

```
import imp
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'myapp/wsgi.py')
application = wsgi.application
```

And also the changes I made to settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : '[name]',
        'USER' : '[user]',
        'PASSWORD' : '[password]',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT' : '3306',
    }
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ BASE_DIR + "/assets", ]
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/[cPanel username]/public_html/static'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/[cPanel username]/public_html/media'
```

I've been trying absolutely everything to get this to work without any progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.